# Two operations in accumulate

Tags: python, functional-programming

I tried to convert the following loop into a `accumulate()` call but i despicably failed:

```
total = 0
for h in heat_values:
    total += h
    total -= total*0.25
```

How can I accumulate the values of h including this 0.25 decay factor?

Background: I wanted to do this as a just for fun exercise simulating a simultaneous heating and cooling process with functional programming style (the add operation is the heating step, and the subtraction is the cooling step). I want to get the accumulated values to plot the values of the process.

Comment: `total -= total*0.25` is `total *= 0.75`, which works fine with `reduce(lambda h, total: (total + h) * 0.75, heat_values, 0.0)`.

Comment: @dhke The signature of your lambda expression is backwards.  It does not matter in this particular case because total and h are just added together and addition is cummutative.  It would, though, if the function were, more realistically, `.75 * total + h`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for pointing that out, `lambda total, h:` is of course the proper order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless my math or reasoning is incorrect this is how you would achieve this using `accumulate`:

```
heatvalues = [20, 30, 40, 50]

list(accumulate(heatvalues, lambda x, y: (x+y)*.75))

>>>[20, 37.5, 58.125, 81.09375]
```

Edit: If you only want the last element, aka the total then it becomes:

```
list(accumulate(heatvalues, lambda x, y: (x+y)*.75))[-1]

>>>81.09375
```

Comment: if you want the last element, you use reduce instead of accumulate.

Comment: I already edited to accommodate for that, and I was simply answering OPs question using the module they attempted to use.

Comment: So to complete this: `reduce(lambda x, y: (x+y)*.75, heat_values)` returns the final total and `accumulate(heat_values, lambda x, y: (x+y)*.75)` gets the intermediate values, what i aimed for (for plotting).

Answer (score 2):

In short, you don't.  **accumulate** operates on an existing iterable type, such as a list of daily production quantities, returning the running total thereof.  You have a recurrence relation, not a ready iterable.  The problem is that **total** depends on a decay operation on the previous values.

If you want to make this a one-liner, I suggest that you use **reduce**, which allows you to specify the reduction function -- i.e. a **lambda** function of your own design.

Comment: heat_values is a ready iterable, otherwise the original for loop wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

[`functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) (just `reduce` in 2.x) can be made to work. The `function` takes two args, the current accumulated value and the new value from the sequence, in that order.

For your problem, subtracting .25 is the same as multiplying by .75.  Either is done after adding the new value.  This should work.

```
from functools import reduce
def update(total, new):
    return .75 * (total + new)
total = reduce(update, heat_values, 0)
```

EDIT: I wrote the above not being aware of the addition of `accumulate` to itertools in 3.2 and of the `func` argument in 3.3.  The doc does not specify the order of the two arguments to `func`, but it is the same as for the `reduce` function: accumulated value, new_value.  This is verified by using an asymmetric update expression such as `.75 * running_total + new_value`.